# Getaddrinfo does not resolve in some kubernetes pod on some hosts

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod where `getaddrinfo` cannot resolve the address to a Kubernetes Service in the same namespace but can connect to the service if I use the IP address instead. Using `tcpdump`, I can confirm that it does not send DNS queries to `nodelocaldns` or to `coredns`. Manually adding the address to `/etc/hosts` does not resolve the issue. The image of the pod is a derivative of https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/datascience-notebook and runs `start-singleuser.sh` as entry point.

If I create a pod on the same machine but only run `sleep` as entry point, everything works. This issue also occurs in some of the newer machines (installed around 2 years after the cluster was initially set up).

Any ideas how to fix or troubleshoot this extremely puzzling issue?

Comment: What Kubernetes version are you using? How have you deployed it? Could you provide a .yaml file of your pod?

Comment: Hello @ChristianAlis. Any updates?

Comment: It's running kubernetes 1.19 installed by kubespray 2.15.1. The cluster has been running for 3 years now so there might be changes that were not migrated properly although I used the defaults mostly. I tried running `start-singleuser.sh` on the working pod but the dns resolution didn't fail afterwards.